# error in applying curve_fit to the logistic function

Tags: python

I need to approximate the input data with two logistic functions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZolk.jpg)

Tell me, please, what could be the reason for the incorrect finding of coefficients in the second case?

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

t = np.array([1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 6])
y = np.array([3, 22, 272, 446, 896, 1222, 1540, 1870, 2072, 2562])


def logistic_1(t, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2):
    return beta_0 / (1 + beta_1 * np.exp(-1 * beta_2 * t))

def logistic_2(t, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, t_0):
    return beta_0 / (1 + beta_1 * np.exp(-beta_2 * t + beta_2*t_0))


args, _ = curve_fit(logistic_1, t, y, method='trf') 
beta_01, beta_11, beta_21 = args[0], args[1], args[2] 
y_fit1 = logistic_1(t, beta_01, beta_11, beta_21)


args1, _ = curve_fit(logistic_2, t, y, method='trf') 
beta_02, beta_12, beta_22, t_02 = args1[0], args1[1], args1[2], args1[3]
y_fit2 = logistic_2(t, beta_02, beta_12, beta_22, t_02)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(t, y, 'o', color='orange')
plt.plot(t, y_fit1, color='black')
plt.plot(t, y_fit2, marker='*')
```

For the first function, by applying method='trf' in the curve_fit function, everything worked out. But for the second with similar data, everything is approximated by a horizontal line[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuDu7.jpg)

Without method='trf' gives the error: warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',

Comment: The method "trf" is ment for optimization within bounds. For your problem, if you add boundaries for your curve_fit as an argument

"bounds=(0, [3000., 200., 3.]))"  for the first fit, for the second one more boundary as t0, of course

you will get the right fits. This is only a partial answer, but it might be a quick fix for you. (The boundaries were chosen already in the range that should be relevant for your function.)

Comment: @Baradrist Thank you very much for your answer, it really helped. But I didn't really understand how to define the boundaries (in particular for t 0). I set 25 and the graph began to display correctly, but I don't understand why. (sorry if the questions are very ask, I'm just just starting to understand this topic)

Comment: The boundaries you give the fit is restricting the parameter to be within them. So, if you give it 25 (and the 0 for the lower bound as given above), it means that the optimal t_0 will be searched for in the interval [0;25]. It would be reasonable to extend this to negative parameter values as well.

Comment: Nevertheless, you'll notice that your second fit is redundant if you look at the rules for power laws (you can check for that by inserting the fitted parameter values!). You can write    beta_11 = beta_12/np.exp(-beta_22*t_02) by just rewriting the exponent (with the minus) as a fraction. ;D

Comment: If you were asking how to choose the parameter boundaries: You will need to look into what they do in the equation. Example: The data is going up to >2500. Your beta_0 is the scaling factor (the rest of the function is <1), so setting it above 2500 made sense. You can take apart your function in this way - answering "what parameter does what?".